# Access Running Excel For Text to Columns (Loop multiple times)

Tags: vba, ms-access, excel

I'm having a problem with my code - I need it to import data multiple times, but I need the data to be properly edited into delimited columns first.

**Basically, when I step into it the program can do the columns to text ONE time. But after that, it fails converting** even though these text files are all formatted the same.

Sample data- As you can see these have delimiters (= and ,)

```
"7",="AR",="",="",="720325438",="491.45",="0.00",="0.00",="0.00",="0.00"
"7",="AR",="",="",="720344843",="40.00",="0.00",="0.00",="0.00",="0.00"
```

code:

```
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet


For intCurrentfileNumber = 1 To intNumOfFiles
strCurrentFolderName = varFileArray(intCurrentfileNumber, 0)
strCurrentFileName = varFileArray(intCurrentfileNumber, 1)

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = True

xlApp.Workbooks.Open strCurrentFolderName & "\" & strCurrentFileName
Set xlSheet = xlApp.Worksheets(1)

xlSheet.("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).TextToColumns _
Destination:=Range("A1"), _
DataType:=xlDelimited, _
TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, _
Tab:=False, _
Semicolon:=False, _
Comma:=True, _
Space:=False, _
Other:=True, _
OtherChar:="=", _
TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

ActiveWorkbook.Close (True)
xlApp.Quit
Set xlApp = Nothing
Set xlSheet = Nothing

DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "Import Specification", "Staging", strCurrentFolderName & "\" & strCurrentFileName, True

Next intCurrentFileNumber
```

Comment: What error does it fail with? Or does it just not do it properly?

Comment: I would not keep starting and quitting Excel within the loop. I would do all the Excel-automation, then quit Excel (once) and then perform all the transfers. I would probably also split these into two separate procedures.

Comment: .. but, looking again at your code, you seem to be attempting to import the same file over and over(?).

Comment: @Cor_Blimey: It just doesn't do it properly. I don't get an exception. The end result is that the majority of the files are left unedited.

Comment: @Andy G - Sorry, I missed the part of the code where it updates the currentfolder and currentfile with an array. I'll see what I can do with only opening excel once and what the result will be. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure where my error quite was - I'm thinking that the error is somewhere in here - actually, after closing and reopening Access it started giving me an error and not letting me run it.

```
xlSheet.("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).TextToColumns _
```

@Andy G - Thank you for the suggestion on not closing/re-opening Excel App - this might be a part of it working as well. However, This is MUCH more of a "ghetto" way of running it - but it seems to be running everything just fine. It opens up all the import texts, adjusts the textToColumns accordingly, and imports them all successfully.

If anyone has a more clean way of doing it, please feel free to chime in. Thanks!

```
xlSheet.Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.TextToColumns , _
Destination:=Range("A1"), _
DataType:=xlDelimited, _
TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, _
Tab:=False, _
Semicolon:=False, _
Comma:=True, _
Space:=False, _
Other:=True, _
OtherChar:="=", _
TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```